# Nested accordion per each tab dosent work

Tags: angular, typescript

When i click on the first tab the corresponding accordion will work proper (display the contents in the accordion) but when i click second tab the accordions of that particular tab display empty view,and the first tabs accordion updated with second tab's content.

Tried with dynamically adding the id tag with the accordion and tab-pane which dint work so please help me with this. (Type Script code with Angular Directives and normal bootstrap tabs)

HTML Code:

Tab Link :

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link fire-safety" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='tab-A'}"
            data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-A" 
            (click)='updateActiveTabs(productCategories[0].productTabID,
                    productCategories[0].ProductCategoryID,
                    productCategories[0].ProductCategoryName)'>
            Fire
            <br>
            & Safety
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link security" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='tab-B'}"
            data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-B" 
            (click)='updateActiveTabs(productCategories[1].productTabID, 
                    productCategories[1].ProductCategoryID, 
                    productCategories[1].ProductCategoryName)'>                    
            Security
            <br>
            & Surveillance
        </a>
    </li>
```

Tab content link:

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show card-body-dsn" id="pane-A" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='tab-A'}"
        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <div *ngFor="let prodCat of product.ProductType; let i = index;">
            <div [attr.id]="'accordionOne_' + i" class="card card-type-full">
                <div class="card-header card-type" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                            [attr.data-parent]="'#accordionOne_' + i" [attr.data-target]="'#collapseOne_' + i"
                            aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapseOne_' + i"
                            (click)="getProductType(prodCat.ProductTypeID,prodCat.ProductTypeName)">
                            <div class="container ml-4 mt-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box">
                                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/cat-type-1.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box2">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p class="type-heading">{{prodCat.ProductTypeName}}</p>
                                                <p class="type-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting
                                                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                                                    ever since the 1500s, when
                                                    an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                                                    type specimen book</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box3">
                                            <p class="view-the-products">View the Products</p>
                                            <img class="view-arrow img-fluid view-img"
                                                src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/down-arrow-red.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div [attr.id]="'collapseOne_' + i" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" *ngFor="let prod of prodCat.Product">
                                    <div class="box-product" (click)="getProductId(prod.ProductID,prod.ProductName)">
                                        <div class="col col-pad-rmv">
                                            <img class="product-img"
                                                src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/product1.png">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <p class="product-name">{{prod.ProductName}}</p>
                                                    <p class="product-desc">lorem ipsum</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <img class="product-go"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/product-go.png">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <a class="row product-hover" *ngIf="prod.IsMaterial"
                                                (click)="getRequirmentType('new requirement')" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#new-requirement-modal">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/new-requirement.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    New<br> Requirement
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="row product-hover" *ngIf="prod.IsSystem"
                                                (click)="getRequirmentType('General')" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#repair-modal">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/AMC-repair.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    AMC/Repair <br>works
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="row product-hover" *ngIf="prod.IsService"
                                                (click)="getRequirmentType('spare/material requirement')"
                                                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#material-modal">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/spare-material.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    Spare/Material<br> Requirement
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of first Tab -->
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade card-body-dsn" id="pane-B" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='tab-B'}" role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <!--Second Tab Contents start-->
        <div *ngFor="let prodCat of product.ProductType; let i = index;">
            <div [attr.id]="'accordionTwo_' + i" class="card card-type-full">
                <div class="card-header card-type" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                            [attr.data-parent]="'#accordionTwo_' + i" [attr.data-target]="'#collapseTwo_' + i"
                            aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="'#collapseTwo_' + i">
                            <div class="container ml-4 mt-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box">
                                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/cat-type-1.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box2">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <p class="type-heading">{{prodCat.ProductTypeName}}</p>
                                                <p class="type-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting
                                                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                                                    ever since the 1500s, when
                                                    an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                                                    type specimen book</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-pad-rmv">
                                        <div class="box3">
                                            <p class="view-the-products">View the Products</p>
                                            <img class="view-arrow img-fluid view-img"
                                                src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/down-arrow-red.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div [attr.id]="'collapseTwo_' + i" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" *ngFor="let prod of prodCat.Product">
                                    <div class="box-product">
                                        <div class="col col-pad-rmv">
                                            <img class="product-img"
                                                src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/product1.png">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <p class="product-name">{{prod.ProductName}}</p>
                                                    <p class="product-desc">lorem ipsum</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <img class="product-go"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/product-go.png">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="row" *ngIf="prod.IsMaterial">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/new-requirement.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    New<br> Requirement
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row" *ngIf="prod.IsSystem">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/AMC-repair.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    AMC/Repair <br>works
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row" *ngIf="prod.IsService">
                                                <img class="overlay-img"
                                                    src="assets/img/cat-tab/type/products/spare-material.png">
                                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                                    Spare/Material<br> Requirement
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Second Tab Contents Ends-->
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click particular tab, the accordion related to that particular tab should open up and display contents.

Currently all the data of other tabs are displayed in the accordion of first tab.

Comment: Could you also post you ts-code for this part? Would be easier to rebuild it on stackblitz then .. The best would be an example on stackblitz :)